# how to limit Xcode Bot to test in only one simulator device

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, server, bots

I am creating Xcode bots on Xcode Server using Xcode 8 and Xcode server 5.2.  when I setup the bot it asks me in the build configuration do I want to run tests (perform test action).  I Check the box and then on the next screen `Devices`, it asks me if I want to run tests on all iOS Simulators or Device, or specific Devices.

[image]

My question is.... is it possible to restrict the simulator to test on only specific devices. i.e. iPad only simulators, etc. I Imagine that this would happen if I changed the app from Universal to iPad only, but wondering if there is another way

Comment: I think you used to be able to do this (I have a bot that I created awhile ago that only runs on one simulator because I want it to be done quickly) but there doesn't appear to be a way to do this anymore.

Comment: OK, I just tried again by selecting "Specific iOS Devices" and all of the Simulators showed up. It hadn't been doing that for several hours. So this appears to be one of the many "sometimes it works / sometimes it doesn't" bits of Xcode bots that I've been plagued with since updating to Xcode 8.3